# How to get Max of Sum of rows in Excel formula?

Tags: excel

I have an excel file in which i have 120 columns and 400 rows. I want to sum up all the rows for 120 columns and get Max of the Sum value. 
How can i achieve it without using array formula

```
A   B   C
1   2   3
2   3   5
3   4   7
4   5   9
5   8   13
4   2   6
```

in this example i should get answer as 43 as the sum of column C is largest

Comment: Why do you want to avoid using an array formula if the array formula does what you want? If you don't want an array formula -- use a helper column. Let D be the sums of A-C then take the max of D. If you want to avoid both helper columns and array formulas -- use VBA to write a custom UDF.

Answer (score 1):

This is a VBA solution which returns either the maximum sum of rows or the maximum sum of columns in a 1-based 2-dimensional array:

```
Function MaxSum(A As Variant, Optional ByRows = True) As Double
'returns the maximum sum of the rows (default) or
'columns of a 1-based 2-dimensional array

    Dim sums As Variant
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, m As Long, n As Long
    Dim sum As Double

    If TypeName(A) = "Range" Then A = A.Value
    m = UBound(A, 1)
    n = UBound(A, 2)
    If ByRows Then
        ReDim sums(1 To m)
        For i = 1 To m
            sum = 0
            For j = 1 To n
                sum = sum + A(i, j)
            Next j
            sums(i) = sum
        Next i
    Else
        ReDim sums(1 To n)
        For i = 1 To n
            sum = 0
            For j = 1 To m
                sum = sum + A(j, i)
            Next j
            sums(i) = sum
        Next i
    End If
    MaxSum = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(sums)    
End Function
```

With your sample data, `=MaxSum(A1:C6)` evaluates to 26 and `=MaxSum(A1:C6, False)` evaluates to 43.

Comment: Works for me. Although strictly speaking you don't need an array - can compare MaxSum to Sum at each step of outer loop.

Comment: @TomSharpe Good point -- I was thinking of how I would use a helper column and the built-in `max` function if I were doing it directly with Excel formulas so I somewhat automatically created a helper-column in memory to feed to `max`. I'll keep it the way it is since it could be helpful if someone e.g. wanted to find things like the average sum or the standard deviation of the sums.

Comment: Agree - it is more versatile like that.